# Using Preference DataStore in Application Class - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, datastore

An error is occurring whenever I am trying to get the saved data for user.
This is where the error is occurring:

```
class Application : Application() {

    private var user: User? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        //Initialize here
    }

    fun setMyUser(userId: String,userPin: String) {
        user = User(userId,userPin)
    }

    fun getMyUser(): User? {
        return user
    }

    init {
        //user = User("","")
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            DataStoreManager(applicationContext).getFromDataStore().catch { e->    //Error 
                e.printStackTrace()
            }.collect {
                if(it.userId.isNotEmpty()) {
                    user = it
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is what my `DataStoreManager` class looks like:

```
class DataStoreManager(private val context: Context) {

    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = userDatastore)

    companion object {
        const val userDatastore = "USER_DATASTORE"
        val userID = stringPreferencesKey("USER_ID")
        val userPin = stringPreferencesKey("USER_PIN")
    }

    suspend fun savetoDataStore(user: User) {
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[userID] = user.userId
            it[userPin] = user.userPin
        }
    }

    suspend fun getFromDataStore() = context.dataStore.data.map {
        User(
            userId = it[userID]?:"",
            userPin = it[userPin]?:""
        )
    }

}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
2022-05-26 22:08:12.235 4139-7972/com.siddydevelops.sms_kotlin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.siddydevelops.sms_kotlin, PID: 4139
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:126)
        at com.siddydevelops.sms_kotlin.Application$1.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:35)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@7248cc7, Dispatchers.IO]
```

Comment: `init` function is executed before onCreate(). You can't access `applicationContext` inside`Application init { }` block. You have to be in onCreate() to access this without errors

Comment: @MatPag Is there a way to get context inside ```init{}``` block?

Comment: No way, and you should not try to do this. Everything context related (except `ContentProviders`) starts in `onCreate()` callback

Comment: As @MatPag said, either use the `App StartUp` library which internally uses `ContentProvider` for early initialization of components or initialize your `DataStore` in `App.onCreate(...)`